# How can I change my code from PHP to HTML?

Tags: php, css, html

I have some code for my website that does not host PHP properly. Switching to a PHP-compatible server is not an option. How can I change it to HTML?

index.php:

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
        <?php
        include("common/common.php")
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            commonheader()
        ?>
        <h1>Coming Soon!</h1>
```

common.php:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css">
</head>
<?php
    function commonheader()
    {
        ?>
        <div class="header"
            <nav>
                <a href="index.php"><button type="button">Home</button></a>
                <!--First Case (unnamed)-->
                <button type="button"><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span></button>
                <!--Second Case (unnamed)-->
                <button type="button"><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span></button>
                <a href="help.php"><button type="button">Help</button></a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

If I need to attach CSS files, I can.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is it something I did?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html and use JS/Ajax.

Comment: you probably got those because you haven't shown any effort. Your question translates to "Stack isn't a free code conversion service". ;-)

Comment: I think that he just over-think the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `php code` and only use `html`

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html"><button type="button">Home</button></a>
                <!--First Case (unnamed)-->
                <button type="button"><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span></button>
                <!--Second Case (unnamed)-->
                <button type="button"><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span></button>
                <a href="help.html"><button type="button">Help</button></a>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <h1>Coming Soon!</h1>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it standardized so I can use it in future webpages for the site?
For example:
Foo.php:
<?php
commonheader();
?>

Comment: i believe that you can find a better way to do this...so, keep learning more about html, and you will see that you will want to standardize a better code ;)

Comment: I don't understand, but whatever. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: "You can't _do_ `Foo.php`"? Sorry if I'm being stupid, but I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Oh ignore that comment, i thought you mean using an object like `Foo.php <?php commonheader();?>`